# how to shuffle characters of strings in bash?

Tags: bash

i have this script where it generates random password but it needs to be shuffled. I couldnt find a way to do it. Please Help me.

```
num=("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "7" "8" "9")
special=("@" "#" "$" "%" "*" "-" "+")
upper=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)
lower=(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)
lower2=${#lower[*]}   #${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}
upper2=${#upper[*]}   #${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}
num2=${#num[*]}     #${num[$((RANDOM%num2))]}
special2=${#special[*]} #${special[$((RANDOM%special2))]}
echo "${special[$((RANDOM%special2))]}${num[$((RANDOM%num2))]}${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}"
```

this is the output: `@7nOyIaJ`
 how do I randomize this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The script uses the `$RANDOM` variable which already introduces some randomness. If you just need a proper random password generator I'd recommend you to use e.g. `pwgen`.

Comment: The script's already outputing random from my runs with it.

Comment: the order is (special number lower upper lower upperlower upper) every time. how to mix this up?

Answer (score 16):

I'm assuming you want it randomized from the sense that "special" is always first. Here's a giant hacky way that does it. **NOTE:** Your script is `scr.bash`.

```
$ echo $(./scr.bash | fold -w1 | shuf | tr -d '\n')
```

#### Examples

```
$ echo $(./scr.bash | fold -w1 | shuf | tr -d '\n')
qT*Jyv8Y

$ echo $(./scr.bash | fold -w1 | shuf | tr -d '\n')
QbOvX3n-

$ echo $(./scr.bash | fold -w1 | shuf | tr -d '\n')
*Q5nGgIt
```

This is rough but shows you the approach.

#### Details

The `fold` command will break the output up into 1 character per line. There are other ways to do this but I opted for `fold`. The `shuf` command can "shuffle" the lines into a random order. The `tr` command will delete the newline characters (`\n`) from the initial fold that we did.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by @slm makes good use of the tools available in the shell but when combined with your ``scr.bash` is a little complicated. If you have Python (either version 2.7 or 3.x) here is a script that does the same job more readably:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Create a formulaic but reasonably strong password.
"""

import random

def shuffled_password():
    """Using one random member of special and num and three members each
       from upper and lower return a shuffled string of their concatenation.
    """
    num = list('012345789')
    special = list('@#$%*-+')
    upper = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    lower = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    random.shuffle(num)
    random.shuffle(special)
    random.shuffle(upper)
    random.shuffle(lower)

    letters = [special[0], num[0]]
    letters.extend(lower[0:3] + upper[0:3])
    random.shuffle(letters)
    s = ''.join(letters)  # funny way to turn list of chars into string
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(shuffled_password())
```

I wrote this code in the course of exploring the combinatoric complexity of your method. Someone above had mentioned using `pwgen`; I initially thought that it must be stronger than your homebrew method, but my guess was wrong.

Your method, even without the `shuffle(letters)` produces 21 billion combinations. This produces an [estimated entropy](http://rumkin.com/tools/password/passchk.php) of 39 bits. This gets a informal rating from Strength Test of:

> 36 - 59 bits = Reasonable; fairly secure passwords for network and company passwords

Adding the final shuffle adds about 5 bits of entropy to the mix. For reference,

```
pwgen --symbols --numerals
```

yields passwords with estimated entropy of 37 bits. I attribute this to pwgen's attempt to produce "memorizable" passwords which reduces the output set somehow. This is still "Reasonable" according to Strength Test's categories.

Caveat: my combinatorial math, particularly in multiset permutations is limited, corrections are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This **pure Bash** solution also **works for multi-byte UTF-8 characters**, if the locale is correctly set (for example `LANG=C.UTF-8`).

We simply use string manipulation and some *bash-friendly* algorithm, such as [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```bash
# shuffle() - shuffle  a string
# $1: The string to shuffle
#
# The string is shuffled using the Fisher–Yates shuffle method :
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle
#
# @return: 0,  output the shuffled string to stdout.
shuffle() {
    local _str="$1" _res
    local -i _i _cur

    for (( _i = ${#_str} ; _i > 0; --_i )); do
        _cur=$((SRANDOM % _i))
        _res+=${_str:$_cur:1}
        _str="${_str:0:_cur}${_str:_cur+1}"
    done
    printf "%s" "$_res"
}
```

Results :

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do echo $(shuffle "@7nOyIaJ"); done
@IJn7Oay
Oa7Jn@yI
Oa@n7IJy
JaO7ny@I
OJI@n7ay
$ for i in {1..5}; do printf "%s\n" $(shuffle "abc山藤123Å"); done
2bca13藤Å山
Åc13藤a山2b
a2b山1c3Å藤
1a3b藤2cÅ山
山3Åc1a2藤b
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158967/43548), and using my own experience in password generation, here's a *nix bash way:

- 1st suggestion gives no guarantee of presence of any group of characters but relies only on `/dev/urandom`, `tr` and `head` which should safely work on most systems
- 2nd suggestion gives a guaranteed presence of characters from each family,  but requires `fold` and `shuf` to be present and behaving the same way as on MacOS

## 1st suggestion - simplest

```
tr_num='0-9' tr_lower='a-z' tr_upper='A-Z' tr_special='%^&.@$*_:.,?-'
# see notes at the bottom on special characters

max_string_len=32

LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc "${tr_num}${tr_lower}${tr_upper}${tr_special}" </dev/urandom | head -c ${max_string_len} ; echo
# or, skipping the variables:
LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc '0-9a-zA-Z%^&.@$*_:.,?-' </dev/urandom | head -c 32 ; echo
```

## 2nd suggestion - guaranteed groups

```
function nix_gen_pwd {
    max_string_len=${1:-32}
    min_char_per_fam=${2:-2}

    tr_num='0-9'
    tr_lower='a-z'
    tr_upper='A-Z'
    tr_special='%^&.@$*_:.,?-' # OR tr_special='!-/:-@[-`{|' OR tr_special=' -/:-@[-`{|'

    remaining_chars="$(( max_string_len - 4 * min_char_per_fam ))"
    if [ $remaining_chars -lt 0 ]; then remaining_chars=0 ; fi

    ( \
          ( LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc "${tr_num}"     </dev/urandom | head -c "${min_char_per_fam}" ) \
        ; ( LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc "${tr_lower}"   </dev/urandom | head -c "${min_char_per_fam}" ) \
        ; ( LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc "${tr_upper}"   </dev/urandom | head -c "${min_char_per_fam}" ) \
        ; ( LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc "${tr_special}" </dev/urandom | head -c "${min_char_per_fam}" ) \
        ; ( LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc "${tr_num}${tr_lower}${tr_upper}${tr_special}" </dev/urandom | head -c "${remaining_chars}" ) \
    ) | fold -w1 | shuf | tr -d '\n' ; echo

}
```

Example:

```
# for i in {1..10} ; do nix_gen_pwd 10 1 ; done
Ex8z6>YI1]
^M1SeHStRx
2&,bD!p-R.
<U>7\Uw3qE
e61A?K3w\n
nEim2n!Cr?
4_\9C2pZTD
`\0m7SRB[m
hIj]o61+i*
8Gnt$q<BX<
```

## Notes on special characters to include in `tr_special`

It's possible to use the `-` expansion of ASCII characters for special chars, similarly to `0-9` and `a-z`
Ref for ASCII table: https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

```
# Arbitrary selection of special chars I want to include
tr_special='%^&.@$*_-:.,?'

# Select special chars using the - expansion of ASCII characters:
# Excluding space character
tr_special='!-/:-@[-`{|'
# Including the space character
tr_special=' -/:-@[-`{|'
```

## Additional notes

It's obviously possible to create special selections, such as:

- upper hexadecimal chars: 0-9A-F
- lower hexadecimal chars: 0-9a-f

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way is ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49598420/4970442)):

```
echo "✨" | grep -o . | shuf | tr -d '\n'
```

Add `xsel -b` at the beginning and at the end to shuffle a string on clipboard.

Answer (score -1):

It seems can be simplified...

```
$ echo {A..Z} {a..z} {0..9} {0..9} '!@#$%^&*()_+=-' | tr ' ' "\n" | shuf | xargs | tr -d ' ' | cut -b 1-18
WhBypH7Pvmtow60D11
```

I added digits twice to guarantee adding them into a password.

And with symbols:

```
$ echo {A..Z} {a..z} {0..9} {0..9} '! @ # % ^ & * ( ) _ + = - [ ] { } " < > . / ?' | tr ' ' "\n" | shuf | xargs | tr -d ' ' | cut -b 1-18
*p6-3XbEBAJL}%>t2U
```