# random output from input

Tags: awk, scripting, string, random

Related question : [how to create a random output from users input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647979/how-to-create-a-random-output-from-users-input)

I was thinking to take an input(only one argument) from user just like `Hello`. And, I want to give output like

```
olleho
llohe
he
llo
lo
```

Just like above. And, I want to make millions of sample from that single input. I want to save those texts in a txt formatted file. How to do it?

---

Suppose, I am giving my email address as an argument `Istiakshovon0@gmail.com`. So, now I want to make possible related password with this account. Some sample output given below :

```
Istiakshovon0@gmail.com
Istiakshovon
Istiak
Ishovon
Ishovon0
Iksgc
gmail
moc
```

I want to create sample password every possible way as possible.

---

I added [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) tag cause, I noticed that lot of peoples were formatting texts using `awk`. I am not familiar with it(I am just a beginner Linux user). That's why I added it.

Comment: I am moving to **Manjaro**. That's why I am not sure if `awk` is available in `Manjaro` or not. If doesn't than I request to tell me..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to shuffle characters of strings in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158959/how-to-shuffle-characters-of-strings-in-bash)

Comment: `read -p "Input: " input; echo $(echo "$input" | fold -w1 | shuf | tr -d '\n')`

Comment: Instead of opening a new question, you should have edited your first question to make it clear.... but you barely responded to the comments.

Comment: awk is available in every linux distro (except possibly some of the tiny distros - and most of those provide at least a minimal awk with busybox).  awk should be in every other kind of unix too.   It's a standard scripting language for unix, more common than bash. or zsh. or perl.

Comment: @pLumo first of all that's not my question. That's why I created the question. And, there's little bit difference. And, you flagged it to shuffle characters of strings in bash. But, that doesn't answer this question cause, I didn't only want to shuffle string's letter. I wanted to something just like this, if user input `hello` output should be `lo,llo,ello,ol,oh,eh,ell,hell,hel,hello`. I want to make millions of possibilities if possible... That's why its not related to shuffling.

Comment: Sure, not 100% the same. However it's similar and combined with other answers here on this platform a valid solution. But you don't show any attempt to solve your problem. This is not a code-writing platform.

Comment: I've no idea what `Manjaro` is but if it's a POSIX platform then by definition it must have `awk`. If it's not POSIX and you don't already know where to find documentation for it then start googling I guess.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain the **exact** reordering of letters you require if it's not simply shuffling. At one point I thought you wanted substrings of the input (including wrapping) but I see `ol` in your desired output and that doesn't exist as a substring of `hello`.

Comment: @EdMorton Look at `hello` from backward. Then, you will see `ol`.

Comment: Of course and if I look at `hello` I also see `hl` with a couple of chars between them - is that part of your desired output or not? You need to explain what it is you want rather than expecting us to guess from just a few lines of sample input. You already have one answer making what I think is probably a wrong guess at what you want but idk, maybe I'm guessing wrong. Until you tell us, we're all just guessing.

Comment: I thought for a second I had figured out you wanted substrings in forward or reverse order using wraparound but then I see `olleho` which is longer than your input string so I was wrong again. As well as telling us how you want the characters rearranged (including where duplication of the chars is allowed) you'll have to also tell us how many characters can be present in the output.

Comment: @EdMorton I hope you would understand my question this time. I have edited my question. And, I didn't accept write anything to that answer cause, I haven't try that command. Or, haven't read properly.

Comment: No, I don't. `every possible way` is extremely vague and would at a minimum include shuffling the characters into any order.

Comment: [A github repo is available to create random text output](https://github.com/Mebus/cupp)

Comment: I think they want every possible permutation of all the characters in the input, from an output length of 1 possibly up to a maximum length of the input itself (otherwise the permutations would be infinite).  Or maybe to some arbitrary length. dunno.  There are many examples of this in many different languages at: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations

Comment: @cas Ohh! Really that's great link!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using perl and the [Algorithm::Permute](https://metacpan.org/release/Algorithm-Permute) library module:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Algorithm::Permute qw(permute);

my $string = 'hello';
my @array = split //, $string;
permute { print join("",@array), "\n" } @array;
```

```
$ ./permute.pl | head
hello
helol
heoll
hoell
ohell
hello
helol
heoll
hoell
ohell
```

The version above only prints permutations of the same length as the original.

The version below does all permutations from length 1 to same length:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Algorithm::Permute;

my $string = shift; # New & Improved! Now takes an argument!

# un-comment only ONE of the following two lines:
#for my $i (reverse 1 .. length($string)) {
for my $i (1 .. length($string)) {

  my $p = Algorithm::Permute->new([split //, $string], $i);
  while (my @res = $p->next) {
    print join('',@res), "\n";
  };
};
```

Save as, e.g., `permute.pl`. Make executable with `chmod +x permute.pl` and run like:

```
$ ./permute.pl hello
```

Note 1: It turns out that there's a known bug [Original array is emptied when doing full permutations](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127086) in the Algorithm::Permute module which erases the array it is called with.

This is decidedly non-perlish behaviour, and is probably because the module isn't native perl, it's a thin perl wrapper around a compiled C function....and the C function was written in a way that destroys the array.

Anyway, that's why I've got rid of the `my @array = split //, $string` line, and used `[split //, $string]` to generate an anonymous array for the the `Algorithm::Permute->new()` method. This ensures the array is recreated on every pass through the loop.

Normally, if an array doesn't (or shouldn't) get modified inside a loop, it should be created just once, outside of the loop.

Note 2: If you want to reverse the order of output, either pipe the output of the script to `tac`, or change the for loop in the script to:

```
for my $i (reverse 1 .. length($string)) {
```

Doing this is what alerted me to the bug.   The updated version above now works with or without `reverse`.

Comment: When I run the code I am getting output `Can't locate Algorithm/Permute.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Algorithm::Permute module) (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.32/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.32/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.32/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at pass.perl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at pass.perl line 4.`. I had installed it from [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/perl-algorithm-permute/). Although I am getting same error.

Comment: Sorry, can't help with Arch packaging issues...but it looks like either the package didn't install properly, or (if it did install OK) it installed the module's files into the wrong directory.  I use Debian, and just installed the .deb package with `apt install libalgorithm-permute-perl`.   If the package is broken, you could try installing it with `cpan Algorithm::Permute` .

Comment: Ohh! Yeah that's not installed properly. Let me try again.. I have solved...! `sudo pacman -U perl-algorithm-permute-0.16-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst`

Comment: BTW, to make it take input from the command line, change `my $string = 'hello';` to `my $string = shift;`.   Then you can run it as `./permute.pl 'hello world'`

Comment: It is more helpful than [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/648255/467213). So, I am marking it as my answer. I want little help also. In this source code it was printing like `he,hel,....`every whole possible way. Is there possible way to reverse it. Like I inputted `Istiakshovon0@gmail.com`. So, outputs `Is,s,t` It is starting from small letters. I want to start from bigger one. `Istiakshovon0@gmail.com, Istiakshovon@gmailc.com..,...`

Comment: Oddly, that is harder to do than it should be.  Normally, I'd just say "use the reverse() function in the for loop", but that causes errors with Algorthm::Permute's `next()` method, probably because it's not native perl, but a thin perl wrapper around compiled C.   The easiest solution is to just pipe the output to `tac`

Comment: it turns out that there's a known bug [Original array is emptied when doing full permutations](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127086) which is causing this.   The solution would be to move the `my @array = split ...` line inside the for loop, then the loop will work normally or in reverse.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the user's input is in the variable `userinput`, then the following `awk` code will generate a never-ending random sampling of that input.

```bsh
userinput=$userinput awk '
    BEGIN {
        s = ENVIRON["userinput"] "\n"
        n = length(s)
        while (1)
            printf "%s", substr(s,int(1+rand()*n),1)
    }'
```

This takes the value of `$userinput`, adds a newline character to the end of the string, and then starts writing random characters from that string until you interrupt the code.  The added newline character ensures that we get newlines in the output every once in a while.

Using `head` command you may limit the number of lines of output. If you want 1000 lines, pipe the output though `head -n 1000`. Testing the first 10 lines of output with `userinput='Hello World!'`:

```
$ userinput='Hello World!'
$ userinput=$userinput awk '
    BEGIN {
        s = ENVIRON["userinput"] "\n"
        n = length(s)
        while (1)
            printf "%s", substr(s,int(1+rand()*n),1)
    }' | head
ld l!lodd loWHe! o
H lolooel
o
eo !lll
WrlHellHod
rlll
o!Hddrd

l!lHelWloodWddeodldHHlo!d l ll oorordeoellrWHledW!!WrW W!l
l!od
```

If you want to delete empty lines, then pass the output through `sed '/./!d'`.

A variant of the command that takes the input string from the first line of input:

```bsh
awk '{
        s = $0 "\n"
        n = length(s)
        while (1)
            printf "%s", substr(s,int(1+rand()*n),1)
    }'
```

Comment: I could be wrong but given [the OPs comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/648230/random-output-from-input?noredirect=1#comment1215211_648230) I don't think that's what they're trying to do, I **think** given the sample outputs provided they might be trying to print substrings in forward or reverse order with wrap-around. We'll see if they update their question to tell us though.

Comment: @EdMorton The example in the question takes the string `Hello` and produces a string that contains two `o` characters. They clearly do not want substrings.

Comment: As you said `generate a never-ending`. Now, the problem is whenever I run the code it takes lot of moment. And, never ends it's process. So, how can I deal with that those texts? And, The process is keep going and going never ending. This is really answer of my question. But, I can't put them in a txt page cause, it's never ending. **Isn't there way to save all of them in a txt file when I click `Ctrl`+`C`**?

Comment: @Softunes I show how to limit the number of lines of output with `head` (if you want 1000, pipe though `head -n 1000`). I also mention how to weed out empty lines. You then just need to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: You might want to throw a `srand()` in there (possible even `-v seed="$RANDOM" ... BEGIN{srand(seed)...` or similar) or you'll get exactly the same set of strings printed every time you call the script with the same input. FWIW I'd never have guessed from the question that this is what the OP wanted so good job on figuring that out!

Comment: @EdMorton This did not seem to be necessary on OpenBSD nor on Ubuntu with their native `awk` implementations. It may be necessary if you need to repeat a particular random sequence though (not just with using `$RANDOM` as seed, obviously).

Comment: Not sure what you mean about not necessary. `awk 'BEGIN{print rand()}` should print the same number every time you call it on that same system. Yes, that is useful if/when you need to repeat a sequence. If you don't though then you call `srand()` first which, with no args, creates a seed based on the current time of day and if you're on a system that measures time of day to the second then every time you call the script within a second you'll get the same output, If the systems tracks tod to nanoseconds, say, then you'll only get the same result every nanosecond.

Comment: `$RANDOM` alone isn't a great seed since it's a relatively short range of numbers so you'll keep getting repeated sequences but you can create a better one using `date` + `$RANDOM`, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton `awk 'BEGIN{print rand()}'` prints different numbers every time on OpenBSD. It prints different numbers on Ubuntu (Focal) if I wait at least one second between each invocation, suggesting that it seeds automatically using the current time with a second's resolution.

Comment: Good to know. That'd be annoying as, given that, you can't test the same generated sequence multiple times. Oh... unless that's what `srand()` does for you on those systems, lets you hard-code a seed. Does `BEGIN{srand(3); print rand()}` always output the same values on each system for repeated invocations? I just checked POSIX and there's nothing to say what rand() should use as a seed if srand() hadn't been called previously.

Comment: @EdMorton If I seed the generator, I get a sequence determined by the seed, both on OpenBSD and on Ubuntu. This is what I alluded to earlier; `seed()` may be useful to repeat a particular sequence, but on these to platforms (at least) it's not strictly needed to get a different sequence by default, since they seem to be self-seeding.

Comment: Right, I was just curious to know if `srand()` behaved as I expected. So for portability: if you want the same sequence of random numbers every time you call awk, call `srand(<some fixed value>)` first, and if you want a different sequence every time, call `srand(<some varying value>)` first. If you call `srand()` without an argument you'll get a different sequence every second or less depending on the systems time of day (POSIX seed) granularity, and if you dont call `srand()` at all before calling `rand()` then you'll get the same or a different sequence depending on your awk implementation.